# My AFK command is only showing one word when I write the reason. Why?

Tags: python, discord, bots

My AFK command works great except for the fact that I can only use one word reasons. Example, I would say -afk walking the dog. Whenever someone pings me in the discord server that I went AFK in it would only say (user) if afk. Reason: Walking. I'm trying to figure out how to make it say multiple words instead of just one.
Here is some of my afk command

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    global afkdict
    if message.author in afkdict:
       afkdict.pop(message.author)

    for member in message.mentions:  
        if member != message.author:  
            if member in afkdict:  
                afkmsg = afkdict[member]  
                await message.channel.send(f" {member} is afk. Reason: {afkmsg}")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to provide the afk command.

I can imagine your mistake tho:

```
@client.command()
async def afk(ctx, *, reason):
    global afkdict
    afkdict[ctx.author] = reason
```

The important thing is the *, which means that everything after that point in the message is pushed into the argument parameter.

e.g
-afk Walking the dog

---> reason is "Walking the Dog"